# Extracting specific information in div tag from a HTTP GET response efficiently

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing

I'm trying to send a HTTP GET request to a page that gives me its response body back which I then wish to parse to extract a specific value from one of the div tags. For example, let's say that the div tag of interest looks like the following:

```
<div id="nameofPlayer">Star Crafter</div>
```

I'm only interested in this div tag's enclosed value, that is in this case 'Star Crafter'.
I'm new to this and have come across several approaches and implementations to do this but am confused and need a simple, efficient way. The code I'm currently using looks like under:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class SB_HRW_Tracker {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SB_HRW_Tracker http = new SB_HRW_Tracker();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();
    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "www.somedummyurl.com";


        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        /* Possible convert the responseCode to JSON here for ease of parsking? */

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to use Regex here to parse the response content for the value enclosed between the specific div tag (combination of regex and some substring functions?). Also, I'm not sure if it would be better to convert the response to JSON for ease of parsing. Any pointers toward how to achieve this easily and efficiently will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could just simply use a regex:

```
    String html = "<html><head><body><div id=\"nameofPlayer\">Star Crafter</div></body></html>";

    // strip out your required data with a regex
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*<div id=\"nameofPlayer\">(.*?)</div>.*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Result:

```
Star Crafter
```

Take a read through: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html

Comment: Well, in your code, you have the response passed to a var here: `response.toString()` so you can pass it into the matcher: `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response.toString());`

Comment: Yes! I did that but still the code returns to me the entire response body instead of just the value 'Star Crafter'. Am I missing something here? What does the matcher.group() do?

Comment: aah never mind, I fixed that little bug! Thanks for sharing the code in the answer but while it seems to be working with your example, there isn't a match for the pattern in the actual responseCode

Comment: Hehe, well.. don't keep us in suspense! What was it?

Comment: See that little print statement at the very end of the code? I had completely forgotten to comment that one out!

Comment: Should I replace the (.*) between the div in the search pattern with [a-z0-9]* because the value can only comprise of alphanumeric characters? I'm not sure if that's the issue here but the Matcher is unable to find the pattern in the response

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue. The first case should match any chars. What you couls do is test your regex quickly using something like: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html If you are stuck, paste the html to pastebin or similar so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Alright, I fixed that now. It seems my head isn't in the right place this morning! Everything seems in order now and the search works. One last glitch: the print statement for matcher.group(1) returns 'Star Crafter' and all the html code after it as well. I don't know why this is happening though!

Comment: Probably will help to use the reluctant qualifier, use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` Is it possible to post the html?

Comment: Can't post the html sorry but no worries I fixed it bu replacing the capturing pattern (.*) to ([a-z0-9]*). This just captured the player's name and any other character was excluded from the match. Thanks for all the help so far, really appreciate it! :)